# ddrescue error: ddrescue: Can't open output file: No such file or directory

Tags: data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a Windows laptop hard drive that failed (500GB).

I tried connecting it to a second computer and it froze the second computer whether it was connected via usb or SATA cable. It was recognized by the BIOS so I booted the second computer with a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS LiveUSB and tried to use ddrescue.

I'm using the following command:

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sda2 media/it/84CEABF4CEABDD24/ImageFileName.img media/it/84CEABF4CEABDD24/TextFileName.txt
```

and I'm getting the error:

`ddrescue: Can't open output file: No such file or directory`

Ive tried creating subfolders and pointing it there. I've tried running the command without the .img or .txt. Still getting the error.

What is the cause of the error and how do I correct it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
sudo ddrescue /dev/sda2 /media/it/84CEABF4CEABDD24/ImageFileName.img /media/it/84CEABF4CEABDD24/TextFileName.txt
```

When you are referring to a file/directory absolutely, you need to put a / in front of it. Without it, you are looking in the current directory